# How to have a rails model have mulitple user_id's in one table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-many-through, seed

I'm developing an assigning system. I need to be able to access the Assignment of the referees to the Game model. The Assignment can have up to 4 referees who are all Users. I believe my associations are correct. My questions are:

1. Do I need to add an assignment_id to the Game table?
2. To test my system I will need to seed data eventually. How do I seed the data/setup the Assignment so that each attribute (center_referee, assistant_referee) is a User? I would like this form to be a drop-down inevitably if it makes a difference.
3. For seed Data, I'm looking for something along the lines of the following (ignore that I'm using `name` instead of `first_name`):

```
Assignment.create(center_referee: user.name, assistant_referee_1: user.name, assistant_referee_2: "user.name", fourth_official: "user.name", game_id: 1)
```

3. Do I need to setup up `accepts_nested_attributes` on the model associations to accomplish all this?

Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :games, through: :assignments
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :assignment
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :user 
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "role"
end

create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string "home_team"
    t.string "away_team"
end

create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string "center_referee"
    t.string "assistant_referee_1"
    t.string "assistant_referee_2"
    t.string "fourth_official"
 
    t.integer "game_id"
end
```

I know this is somewhat of a loaded question but I've been scratching my head over this for quite sometime now.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to what @Vijay said,

As you want to have multiple user_ids in single table, I would suggest you to name the association, for example: In `assignment.rb` as `belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: 'User'`

You can also keep the association optional by using `optional: true`.

> Do I need to add an assignment_id to the Game table?

No, Here `Assignment belongs_to Game` so id should be present in the Assignment model(as an assignment cannot exist without a game but the game is independent of assignment).

If this was about accessing the assignment for a given game, you can try `game.assignment`.

> Do I need to setup up accepts_nested_attributes on the model associations to accomplish all this?

`accepts_nested_attributes` is used if you want to accept attributes for the associated model(Assignment) while accepting attributes for the model(Game).
for more info [checkout](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

> To test my system I will need to seed data eventually. How do I seed the data/setup the Assignment so that each attribute (center_referee, assistant_referee) is a User? I would like this form to be a drop-down inevitably if it makes a difference.

I don't quiet get your this question, but checkout if this helps:
`f.collection_select(:center_referee_id, User.all, :id, :name )`

Hope this helped.

Comment: I like that you said to use `optional: true`, I also think it's worth noting that I should add `dependent: :destroy` on `has_one :assignment` as well so that if a game is deleted, the assignment is as well. Don't worry about the `accepts_nested_attributes` part, that's a question for when I get to making the actual form for all of this. I do see how I would do it with `f.collection` though, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Assignment` class, the `belongs_to` for `game` is correctly correlated to the database schema. But, the `belongs_to :user` is incorrect - there is no `assignments.user_id` column in the db.
I think you want 4 columns, but each of them referring back to the `users` table with a different name - is that correct? If so, then your model should have the `belongs_to` with the appropriate option for `class`.

Since you mention that these are optional, you will have to also specify the `allow_null` appropriately.

btw, your `games` table and the corresponding `Game` model are also not correlating correctly.

I think you need to start with only 2 tables, logically model them correctly to satisfy the one-to-one, one-to-many relationships. Once this is done, then "translate" that into the rails model DSL. currently, this all seems very hay-wire.

Comment: So you said my `belongs_to :user` is incorrect in my Assignment model. If I needed to call `assignment.users` or even `user.assignments` how would I accomplish that? Or are you saying to scrap the `belongs_to :user` and instead go with `belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: User` and do that for each "user" in the assignment? And can you be more specific on what's wrong with the Games table and model?

Comment: Yes - I meant to have a `belongs_to` for each association of `User`.


```
belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :assistant_referee_1, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :assistant_referee_2, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :fourth_official, class_name: 'User'
```

And you would call it as `assignment.center_referree`, etc

Answer (score 0):

```
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string "center_referee"
    t.string "assistant_referee_1"
    t.string "assistant_referee_2"
    t.string "fourth_official"
 
    t.integer "game_id"
end
```

Looks like you currently have this. What you need to do is to have a change of the types to as below:

```
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "center_referee_id"
    t.integer "assistant_referee_1_id"
    t.integer "assistant_referee_2_id"
    t.integer "fourth_official_id"
 
    t.integer "game_id"
  end
```

This is going to work because, as you are passing the `belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: "User"` to the model, `ActiveRecord` is intelligent enough to query the ids on the user table.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```center_referee_id``` instead of ```center_referee```? I gave both a try and now the assignment isn't created

Comment: Oh not really, because you're adding the class_name, rails will know what to do at the model level.

Comment: So I've played with it and if I add anything else into my Assignment model, it will not create the assignment, I'm going to make a separate SO question for it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I figured it out, was missing ```accepts_nested_attributes_for :game``` and ```optional: true```

Comment: Oh shoot.. haha that was it actually. I hope it works now/

Comment: Works perfectly, couldn't have done it without you!