# Pass in MODEL_id to another model params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, associations

I have two models: Game and Assignment. When I create a Game, I want to automaticall create an Assignment to go along with that game, hence the association between the two. In my Game controller I have:

```
def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: "Game was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
   def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:home_team, :away_team)
    end

    def assignment_params
      params.require(:assignment).permit(@game.game_id)
    end
end
```

How do I pass in the game_id to the Assignment params when the Game is created? My models below incase they're needed. There is a `game_id` column in my Assignment model.

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :assignment, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game

    belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "user_id"
    belongs_to :assistant_referee_1, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "user_id"
    belongs_to :assistant_referee_2, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

Game Form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :home_team %>
    <%= f.input :away_team %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Game Controller

```
def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  # POST /games or /games.json
  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: "Game was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: If you always create the assignment in the game, you can just do it in the game model, no need to burden the controller with it. Check out nested attributes.

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: Game form added above. I have moved the create_assignment to the Game model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right of the top of my head, you could simply run a simple callback inside the Game model as follows:

```
after_create :create_assignment    

def create_assignment
  Assignment.create(game_id: id, center_referee_id: , assistant_referee_1_id:, assistant_referee_2_id:)
end
```

This way you handle it once at the model level. Every game created automatically creates an assignment.

Also if the `referees` are not required, you may pass an `optional: true` flag to the `belongs_to` in the `assignment` model. that way you can safely create the games. because currently, it is not clear how you're getting the referee details from.

Comment: So this runs fine except the Assignment isn't created. In the logs I get: ```Game Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/game.rb:10:in `create_assignment'
  TRANSACTION (1.0ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/games_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'```

Comment: Not sure what "block in create" means

Comment: hmm, it's giving a hint on line 27 in your `games_controller` could you share what is on there? or maybe change `after_create` to `after_save`

Comment: game controller posted above

Comment: Yes i see that it is posted above but the transaction throws that  `↳ app/controllers/games_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'` that's why i wanted to see on line 27. 


So it seems your `Assignment` requires more than just a `game_id` it belongs to thos 3 other params.

Comment: So line 27 specifically is ```if @game.save```. I tried changing it in the model to ```after_save :create_assignment``` and no luck there either. And yes there are 3 other params but those are set elsehwere. I just need it so when a Game is created an Assignment is created and "linked" to that game via the game_id

Comment: Yeah, i think it's not saving because it `belongs_to` the other referees too. so we may have to change the implementation.

Comment: I commented out the other 3 belongs to and success. Now I need to figure out the belongs_to :user stuff again. Link here if you want to take a gander at a question I asked about my other issue Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569165/how-to-have-a-rails-model-have-mulitple-user-ids-in-one-table/68569836?noredirect=1#comment121214670_68569836

Comment: Checked it out and added an answer. Also could you mark this as a selected answer?